# Merge different tables Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two tables that have nothing in common and I would like a query that gives the results of both but I don't know how to proceed
Article table:

```
id   id_user     article     lang   time
1    1           something   en     327367
2    2           something   en     364756
```

Product table:

```
id   id_buyer   id_seler   time_product
1    1          1          463737
2    2          1          487474
```

Expected result:

```
id      id_user     article     lang   time     id      id_buyer   id_seler   time_product
1       1           something   en     327367   null    null       null       null
2       2           something   en     364756   null    null       null       null
null    null        null        null   null     1       1          1          463737
null    null        null        null   null     2       2          1          487474
```

I've read about union but I'm not sure I can apply it here.
I would like a page that indifferently lists items and products ordered on time

Comment: The two tables do not have the same number of columns @Frankich

Comment: *Expected result:* Impossible - server will fail because of output column names are duplicated.

Comment: I can change the column name @Akina

Comment: May I ask what this is for? It seems a bit strange to create one result set from two unrelated tables? Why not just have two result sets?

Comment: I need a page that lists articles and products sorted by date. I could use two queries, one for the products and one for the articles but then I don't know how to sort them by date @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id t1id, id_user, article, lang, `time` t1time, 
       NULL t2id, NULL id_buyer, NULL id_seler, NULL t2time
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
       id, id_buyer, id_seler, `time`
FROM table2
/* ORDER BY t1id IS NULL, t1id, t2id */
```